# I want to customize the color of the meter tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to make a meter like the following image.
I want to change the color of the Meter tag to red for the part where the value over 75 area only.
(If value is over 75, everything turns red. I want to keep blue and red area)

Ideal meter
[image]

My meter

[image]

React.js

```
<div className="climate_icon_and_slider_section">
    <div className='ic_thermometer_and_meter'>
      <img className="ic_thermometer_for_detail_page" src= {ic_thermometer_for_detail_page} />
    
      <meter max="95" min="45" high="75" value={temperature_value}></meter>
    </div>
    
    <div className="range-container-climate">
      <input className="range-input" type="range" name="speed" min="45" max="95" 
      value={temperature_value} onChange={handleSliderChange}></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ic_thermometer_and_meter {
  position: relative;
}

.ic_thermometer_for_detail_page {
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;
  right: -100px;
}

meter {
  width: 265px;
  height: 98px;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: -83px;
  z-index: 7;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {background: gray;} /*background color of bar*/
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {background: #0D76BE;}
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value{background:red;}
```

Comment: you actually have the ideal meter already. If you replace `background: gray` in `-webkit-meter-bar` to  `background: red`, and set the current red to blue. I think that would do what you want

Comment: Thanks but I should keep background color gray. Please watch the ideal meter here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPAwMofPW28

Answer (score 0):

```
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {background: gray;} /*background color of bar*/
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {background: #0D76BE;}
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value{background: linear-gradient(to right, #0D76BE 159px, red 159px)};
```

works!